# Total number of nodes based on content type

Tags: nodes

I have 3 content types and I want to add a section to my site that displays the total number of nodes that each content type has.

However I don't want them to display per content type, i want the total number of all 3 to appear.

So basically nodes in A + B + C = total number of nodes

Is this possible?

Comment: use views and aggregation with in views

Answer (score 2):

In your views, section "OTHER", use **aggregation**.

It will provide you with options like COUNT in your views fields. You then can simply use the nid field, with a content type filter, and then display the count of the nodes.

Comment: I am going to go ahead and assume that the "OTHER" section is a part of Views 3. The site that I am working on was created only using Views 2. 
Is there still the upgrade problem with Views? I might have to try upgrade it.

Comment: Upgrading it is always a good thing :)